# Rspec get request not hitting controller (401 Unauthorized error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rspec, get, endpoint

Hey guys can anyone find where i've gone wrong? Ive created an API end point that expects to be called from another website with parameters. From those parameters i'm meant to find a user in my app and update an attribute of that user. This is how my controller looks:

```
class Vodacom::Api::V1::SmsReceiverController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => [:suspend_account]

  def suspend_account
   logger.info "PARAMS: #{params.inspect}"
   @user = User.find_by(guardian_number: localize_number(vodacom_params[:num]), cell_number: vodacom_params[:mesg])
   begin
    @user.update(guardian_verified: false) if @user.older_than_18? == false
    render status: :ok, json: { message: "Account Deactivated" }
   rescue
     render status: :ok, json: { message: "Couldn't find user" }
    end
  end

 def localize_number(num)
  num = num.sub(/^../, '0')
 end

 private

 def vodacom_params
  params.permit(:num, :mesg, :prem, :tonum, :id)
 end
end
```

My route looks like this:

```
 namespace :vodacom do
    namespace :api do
      namespace :v1 do
        get "/suspend_account", to: "sms_receiver#suspend_account"
      end
    end
  end
```

My specs for this functionality look like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Vodacom::Api::V1::SmsReceiverController, :type => :controller do

  describe "When the correct parameters are sent to the SMS receiver controller" do
    let(:user){ create(:user, guardian_number: "0798900606", cell_number: "0798900606")}
    let(:params){ {prem: "30911", mesg: "0798900606", num: "27798900606", tonum: "082007005922721", id: "1122365"} }

    it "should receive a query string with attributes" do
      expect(suspend_user_account.request.env['QUERY_STRING']).to eq("id=1122365&mesg=0798900606&num=27798900606&prem=30911&tonum=082007005922721")
    end

    it "should find and disable the user's account " do
      get :suspend_account, params
      user.reload
      expect(user.guardian_verified).to eq(false)
    end

  end
end
```

The Api should find the user with the corresponding cellphone number and change their "guardian verified" attribute to "false". However, when I run the spec it throws this error in the test logs:

```
Processing by Vodacom::Api::V1::SmsReceiverController#suspend_account as HTML
  Parameters: {"prem"=>"30911", "mesg"=>"0798900606", "num"=>"27798900606", "tonum"=>"082007005922721", "id"=>"1122365"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
```

However, the functionality itself works, but the spec doesnt. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

Before you send the request you have to add authorization headers into the request.

Example:

```
 request.headers["Authorization"] = "..."
 request.headers["X-Api-Key"] = "..."
 request.headers["Content-Type"] = "..."
```